# How to get this structure in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dataset

I need to get the following structure in python - 
[[1,2],[22,37],[92,34]]. I just need to know how to create this structure and how to add elements to it. I wish to plot a scatter plot using these values as described [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-scatterplot)

Thank You

Comment: What would be the input you want to convert? If there's none `a=[[1,2],[22,37],[92,34]]` and `a+=[[12,12]]` would seem to work...?

Comment: I would like to start with a = [] and then add the values after fetching them from a table. Thus progressively adding values to a till I reach the end of table

Comment: It does work. Thank you Joachim. Do you want to add it as an answer so that I can accept it? Though I think I have asked a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 0):

To append a list of coordinates to a list, you can simply use `+=`;

```
>>> coords = []
>>> coords += [[10,20]]
>>> coords += [[30,40]]

>>> print coords
[[10, 20], [30, 40]]
```